# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Results.jsp(4,5) Invalid standard action

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" version="2.0">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/embeds/header.jsp"/>
  <div class="content">
    <h>Hotel Results</h>
    <table cellpadding="15">
    <c:forEach var="result" items="${search}">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 8px 10px">
            <c:out value="${search.roomDescription}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a `room` object that holds the `int id` and `String roomDescription` and I wanted to print these out from the arraylist i've used to store all the rooms from the results I got through `ResultSet`. This code seems to error with

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Results.jsp(4,5) Invalid standard action`

Can someone tell me whats wrong with it? (My room class consists of those two variables and getters and setters). I've tested the size of the array list and I know I'm adding in room objects.

Comment: You should be using `${result.roomDescription}` instead, but I can't explain how that's related to this exception. Are you implying that this exception disappears when you remove the `<c:forEach>`?

Comment: Is the room object bound to the request scope with the name "search" ? ${search.roomDescription} is wrong. It should be ${result.roomDescription}.... let me know if this works.

Comment: @verisimilitude in my servlet I have `rsList = (ArrayList <Room>)request.getSession().getAttribute("search");`

Comment: The exception seems to be complaining about line 4 of your JSP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem that is causing the exception is caused by the `<jsp:root>` element, which according to [this page](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref123.html) is malformed.  If I am reading the linked page correctly, there should be a matching `</jsp:root>` tag at the end of the JSP.

Even if this isn't the exact problem, the exception messages says that the problem is at "[4,5]": i.e. line #4 character #5 of the JSP file.

Comment: removing that line causes `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Results.jsp(21,1) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions`

Comment: @SNpn - rather than randomly removing stuff, read the linked page and figure out if what is there is 1) correct, and 2) doing what you want / need it to do in that context.

Comment: @SNpn - and consider that the "new" error at [21, 1] may simply be a different error that the first error was masking.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem.

I was declaring a *taglib* before the `<jsp:root>`, like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="psc" %>

<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
```

I inverted their order, and solved this issue

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">  

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="psc" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="result" items="${search}">
<tr>
    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 8px 10px">
        <c:out value="${result.id}"/>
        <c:out value="${result.roomDescription}"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

search attribute has to return a list of room objects, where they are iterated and displayed. you need to use the result variable that the values get assigned to.

Comment: This doesn't explain the exception and is likely completely unrelated.

Comment: remove the line 4 of the JSP 


<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" version="2.0">



JSTL lib declaration is done in 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Comment: @Sanath: OP seems to be using JSPX where scriptlets won't work.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/475967/JSP/java/Strange-JSP-error-Invalid-Standard
if possible, try to convert the .jspx to a JSP and use jsp specific tags to see if you can run it successfully..<jsp:root> tag has the issue it seems..